# A J2ME lisp?

Tags: java-me, lisp, smalltalk

It seems that programming ON a mobile device (instead of FOR a mobile device) could be easier if a lisp existed that run on J2ME.

Do you know any (preferably opensource) lisp/smalltalk apps?
I searched the web and I couldn't find a working J2ME lisp. 
Is it so difficult to port it to J2ME?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed myself to make http://norvig.com/jscheme.html work in j2me, by removing all UI related classes...It worked, but my cellphone is TOO small and I dont have the time...
I've only tested it with some (fac n)... but lisp is not for me, I'm not that smart.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this tiny lisp will run on J2ME: https://www.iam.unibe.ch/scg/svn_repos/Sources/Cells/src/lisp/

If you give it a try, let me know how it worked...

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Kawa](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/), but I am not certain it will run.